# Get cached Data of webpage in my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am using NSUrlConnection to grab some data from a web service that returns JSON data when I hit a url but sometimes the page goes down or something is wrong.

Is there a way to use the cached version of the url in my iOS App to grab that data when the webpage returns a 404?

In the browser if I go to cache:mysite.com/test.php I can see the JSON data even when the page is down but when I try to use the same url in my iOS App, I do not get the JSON data back.

Is there maybe an Obj C class I am not aware of or an option for the NSUrlConnection?

Comment: As you make requests and the requests are successful, why don't you just store them in a cache of your own, it can be a custom object that persists (core data, sqllite, etc)? And then any future call that fails you can fetch from your cache, and let the user know that the call failed and that you're presenting them with a cached version last fetched at whatever date you specify in your cache metadata.

Comment: That's what I would do in any other case but specifically for this app I want to look at the web pages cache. I have seen it done before but I cannot find any information on how to do it myself.

Comment: Gotcha, in fact, now that I have looked into this more, this actually sounds like a good practice to follow for everyone's app.  See http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/ But I don't know how to specifically force the use of the cache when a 404 occurs other than creating your own cache to use in only those situations and use the NSUrlCache in _normal_ situations.

Comment: Excellent articles! I must say, NSHipster is an amazing source for Obj C!However, reading through both articles, they explain how to cache data when a response has already been grabbed along with its data. What I am looking for is how to get the cached version of the url before I even decide what to do with the data it returns.

Comment: You could subclass NSURLCACHE, you'll have to play with their implementation since in your case you want to use the cache for 404, or quite possibly when 500 errors occur.... http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/

Comment: The information in the black pixel article has not been accurate for several years.

Comment: @quellish, thanks for the heads up on the article.  I've removed the comment to save any future readers potential confusion/complications.

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLConnection` [already uses a cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001843-BAJEAIEE). By default it only caches responses in-memory, you can customize this by setting it to also use on-disk storage:

```
NSURLCache *result = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:[(1024*1024*512) diskCapacity:(1024*1024*1024 * 100) diskPath@"Cache.db"]:
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:result];
```

The reason you are seeing the behavior you describe in your question is that the remote web service is telling your client not to cache the response. You can check this using [REDbot](https://red-bot.org) or a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com). By default `NSURLRequest` will use the protocol's caching policy and semantics, which is almost always the correct thing to do. You can specify a different cache policy by changing the `cachePolicy` property of the `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: I totally understand the reason of this behavior but I am not very certain I understood how I can make use of the cache data. The cachePolicy property is set to the default because I noticed that the other options are mostly for cases of not using cache. Could you please collaborate on how to grab that cache data?

Comment: That depends very much on what you need your application to do. For example, `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` will use the cache unless there is no cached response, in which case it will talk to the server. `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` will always use the cache, and never attempt to use the server. You can also access the `NSURLCache` directly to access a cached response based on your application logic. Without knowing your application's needs I cannot provide more specific guidance than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After much search, I didn't find a way to get a cached version of a web page in my iOS app but I handled the 404 error by looking for the response status code and using a service like Google Cache or archive.org/web/ to get the cached version of the url if a 404 was found.

Might not be the most delicate way but I could not find another way to get a cached version of the website when making the request.